# ScrollController does not connect to ListView

Tags: listview, flutter

Although I add the ScrollController to the ListView, the client of the ScrollController does not appear.
Result of print : ScrollController#a6158(no clients)

```
ScrollController sc = new ScrollController();
ListView(
  controller: sc,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
  ],
);
print(sc.toString());
```

Comment: Please add more details for clarification

Comment: Do you have a scrollcontroller listener? If you have a fixed number of items try ListView.builder and set the itemcount

Comment: @F-1 My actual code uses ListView.builder but nothing changes. I wrote in this form for simplicity. Also there is no listener for sc

Comment: Where dif you added **print(sc.toString());** after adding controller or before. It depands.

Comment: Just like in the code above.